# Google Analytics API: filter by multiple URIs?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

The issue is that i need to filter around 100 analytics URIs which is located in database(lets say most important pages of site), it can be queried one by one but i think it is not efficient. The goal is to filter all URIs at once.
instead of

`filters=ga:pagePath==/firstURI`

i need some thing like

`filters=ga:pagePath==/firstURI && /secondURI && /thirdURI && /...URI`

I have played with http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?csw=1 and searched documentation about it, but couldn't find anything! I hope you will be able to help me!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After very long and unpleasant play with **Google Analytics Query Explorer 2** i came with solution like this one which does right job.

`filters=ga:pagePath==/firstURI,ga:pagePath==/secondURI`

**IMPORTANT NO SPACES** between filters

[Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)

**Combining Filters**

Filters can be combined using OR and AND boolean logic. This allows you to effectively extend the 128 character limit of a filter expression.
OR

The OR operator is defined using a comma (,). It takes precedence over the AND operator and may NOT be used to combine dimensions and metrics in the same expression.

*Examples:* (each must be URL encoded)

Country is either (United States OR Canada):
`ga:country==United%20States,ga:country==Canada`

Firefox users on (Windows OR Macintosh) operating systems:
`ga:browser==Firefox;ga:operatingSystem==Windows,ga:operatingSystem==Macintosh`
AND

The AND operator is defined using a semi-colon (;). It is preceded by the OR operator and CAN be used to combine dimensions and metrics in the same expression.

*Examples:* (each must be URL encoded)

*Country is United States AND the browser is Firefox:*
`ga:country==United%20States;ga:browser==Firefox`

*Country is United States AND language does not start with 'en':*
`ga:country==United%20States;ga:language!~^en.*`

*Operating system is (Windows OR Macintosh) AND browser is (Firefox OR Chrome):*
**`ga:operatingSystem==Windows,ga:operatingSystem==Macintosh;`**

**`ga:browser==Firefox,ga:browser==Chrome`**

*Country is United States AND visits are greater than 5:*
`ga:country==United%20States;ga:visits>5`

Comment: Very helpful answer, didn't know about the AND operator `;`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this using regex and the Destination Page dimension:

```
ga:searchDestinationPage=~^(pagePath1|pagePath2|pagePath3)
```

Remember that a hat (^) in regex means to start at the beginning of the string, which means you need to be sure to include any leading slashes (/) in your page path entries.